# AlarmManager setRepeting not working

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to create an alarm that fires a notification every hour.

My code does work on my emulator android 8.0 but on my device it doesn't, I have oneplus 3T android 8.0. I did allowed to my app in my phone to show notification.

I do this in the onCreate.

```
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
intent = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

am.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

This is what I do in the onDestroy

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
    // telling the client thread to close
    c.setCommand(6);

    // setting an notification alarm every hour
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60, pendingIntent);

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

update:

I found out that the AlarmManager isn't firing my notification when the app is close, so have I need to use service that will set the AlaramManager?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby):

> Standard `AlarmManager` alarms (including setExact() and setWindow())
>   are deferred to the next maintenance window.
>
> - If you need to set alarms that fire while in Doze, use setAndAllowWhileIdle() or setExactAndAllowWhileIdle().
> - Alarms set with setAlarmClock() continue to fire normally — the system exits Doze shortly before those alarms fire.

It is working on your emulator because you might not be testing with Doze mode enabled.

If your use case don't need to be triggered at specific time, consider using `WorkManager`.

Comment: But my phone isn't idle. I test the alarm when my phone screen is on.

Answer (score 0):

To show notification in android 8.0 you need to use NotificationChannel, without defining notification channel, you can not display notification from any of the source (in your case using AlarmManager)

for Android Version > 8.0 (Oreo)

```
// Setup a NotificationChannel
public static final String ALARM_CHANNEL_ID = "alarm";
public static final String ALARM_CHANNEL_NAME = "Alarm Channel";

NotificationChannel alarmNotificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(ALARM_CHANNEL_ID, ALARM_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
    String description = "Media playback controls";
    playNotificationChannel.setDescription(description);
    playNotificationChannel.setShowBadge(false);
    playNotificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    getNotificationManager().createNotificationChannel(playNotificationChannel);

    notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                                .SetChannelId(ALARM_CHANNEL_ID)
                                .SetContentTitle(title)
                                .SetContentText(message)
                                .SetAutoCancel(true)
                                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
                                .SetContentIntent(pending)
                                .Build();
    //use the notification as you are already using it.
}
```

Comment: I do use NotificationChannel. I wrote that the notification code is working  on my emuletor but not on my phone, both of them running on 8.0

Comment: Then use this, public void setExactAndAllowWhileIdle (int type, 
                long triggerAtMillis, 
                PendingIntent operation) //instead of setRepeating. to wakeup the device in idle mode too.

Comment: But my phone isn't idle. I test the alarm when my phone screen is on.